# Why isn't validate being called on my IValidatableObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view model:

```
public class SelectVendorViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Display(Name = "Document Date")]
    [RequiredUnless("IsPidDv")]
    public DateTime? DocumentDate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Document Number")]
    [RequiredUnless("IsPidDv")]
    public int? DocumentNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Vendor")]
    [RequiredUnless("IsPidDv")]
    public Guid? VendorId { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> Vendors { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="PID/DV")]
    public bool IsPidDv { get; set; }

    public Guid? SalesReportId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return SelectVendorViewModelValidator.ValidateSalesReport(validationContext, this);
    }
}
```

A custom model binder:

```
internal class SelectVendorViewModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder, IModelBinder<SelectVendorViewModel>
{
    private readonly IVendorUnitOfWork _uow;

    public SelectVendorViewModelBinder(IVendorUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = bindingContext.Model as SelectVendorViewModel;

        if (model == null || !model.VendorId.HasValue || !model.DocumentDate.HasValue || !model.DocumentNumber.HasValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        var salesReport = _uow.SalesReportRepository.GetSalesReport(model.VendorId.Value, model.DocumentNumber.Value,
            model.DocumentDate.Value);
        if (salesReport != null)
        {
            model.SalesReportId = salesReport.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

And a validator:

```
internal class SelectVendorViewModelValidator
{
    internal static IEnumerable<ValidationResult> ValidateSalesReport(ValidationContext validationContext, SelectVendorViewModel viewModel)
    {
        if (viewModel.IsPidDv)
        {
            yield break;
        }

        if (!viewModel.SalesReportId.HasValue || viewModel.SalesReportId.Value == default(Guid))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Sales report document does not exist.");
        }
    }
}
```

And the controller action that is being posted to:

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult SelectVendor(SelectVendorViewModel selectVendorVM)
{
    selectVendorVM.Vendors = GetVendors();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(selectVendorVM);
    }           

    return RedirectToAction(MVC.Licensing.Endorsements.Create(selectVendorVM.SalesReportId));
}
```

The binder is running correctly, I can step through it in the debugger. But the `SelectVendorViewModel.Validate` method is never called. The property validation passes, and if I set a breakpoint in the controller action `ModelState.IsValid` is true. I thought it might be something with the custom `RequiredUnless` annotation, but even when I remove them the validation doesn't work. I use this same pattern in lots of places in this app but this is the only one that doesn't work. The only difference I could find between this and the others is the `RequiredUnless` annotation and I was able to rule that out. What am I missing?

EDIT: Here's how I register the model binders:

Custom `IModelBinderProvider`:

```
public class GenericModelBinder : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(Type modelType)
    {
        var genericBinder = typeof(IModelBinder<>).MakeGenericType(modelType);

        var binder = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(genericBinder) as IModelBinder;

        return binder;
    }
}
```

In Global.asax Application_Start method:

```
ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(new GenericModelBinder());
```

And in the Ninject config:

```
kernel.Bind<IModelBinder<SelectVendorViewModel>>().To<SelectVendorViewModelBinder>();
```

Comment: If you mock this call:  var salesReport = _uow.SalesReportRepository.GetSalesReport(model.VendorId.Value, model.DocumentNumber.Value,
            model.DocumentDate.Value); to  var salesReport = new MockSalesReport(); does it  call validate then?

Comment: Or otherwise just replace all this var salesReport = _uow.SalesReportRepository.GetSalesReport(model.VendorId.Value, model.DocumentNumber.Value,
            model.DocumentDate.Value);
        if (salesReport != null)
        {
            model.SalesReportId = salesReport.Id;
        } with model.SalesReportId = new Guid(); in order to test.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, just tried it and it still doesn't get called

Comment: Ok well generally speaking when MVC validates a model, it runs through the DataAnnotation attributes and if any of them fail it won't call the Validate method because often the Validate method will have expensive calls to databases for business rule validation, etc so it makes sense to short circuit validation when simple things like annotations fail in order not to waste time and resources proceeding to validate bigger things but given yours is such a simple model.... i cant spot anything obvious.

Comment: Me neither, I'm stuck :(

Comment: How are you registering the model binder?

Comment: Custom `ModelBinderProvider`, I'll edit the question to add the code.

Comment: And do you get any "error hits" running this? if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        var errors = model.Validate(new ValidationContext(model, null, null));
        foreach (var error in errors)                                 
            foreach (var memberName in error.MemberNames)
                ModelState.AddModelError(memberName, error.ErrorMessage); or as the first line of your action method i.e. pre:  if (!ModelState.IsValid)

Comment: I haven't inspected the contents of ModelState directly, but in the controller action ModelState.IsValid is true when I step through it. I'll inspect the contents.

Comment: Nothing in the contents. There are 4 key/value pairs, all of them have 0 errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh (cringe) you're not calling the base method of the `ModelBinder` which in turn calls the Validate method on the model. ;)

```
protected override void OnModelUpdated(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var model = bindingContext.Model as SelectVendorViewModel;

        if (model == null || !model.VendorId.HasValue || !model.DocumentDate.HasValue || !model.DocumentNumber.HasValue)
        {
            return;
        }

        var salesReport = _uow.SalesReportRepository.GetSalesReport(model.VendorId.Value, model.DocumentNumber.Value,
            model.DocumentDate.Value);
        if (salesReport != null)
        {
            model.SalesReportId = salesReport.Id;
        }
       // this is important as we overrode but still need base 
       // functionality to effect a validate
       base.OnModelUpdated(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
```

Comment: Haha, I was actually just typing up my own answer, I think we saw it at the same time. It's always something simple I overlook that gets me stumped. Thanks for the help!